# How do I inject AuthorizationCheckerInterface into a Symfony 4 service

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, symfony4

To start: this is a Symfony 4 application.

I have a console command that requires the injection of a service.

That service requires the AuthorizationChecker (AuthorizationCheckerInterface).

If I let autowiring do its thing, using a type hint in the constructor, Symfony is happy with that much. Unfortunately, the constructor requires two additional parameters that are strings.

So, I add an entry to the services.yaml file with:

```
MyBundle\Utility:
  autowire: false
  arguments:
  - '@AuthorizationChecker' # or AuthorizationCheckerInterface
  - '%kernel.environment%'
  - '%kernel.cache_dir
```

Symfony now complains:

> The service "MyBundle\Command\ListCommand" has a dependency on a non-existent service "AuthorizationChecker".

Note that the service that is missing the AuthorizationChecker is the command, not Utility. Odd.

**Update 1**:
The symfony/security component is installed:

```
grep -i security composer.json
        "symfony/security": "^4.0",
```

console debug:container doesn't show the authorization checker:

```
$ console debug:container --show-private |grep -i checker
  config.resource.self_checking_resource_checker                                                             Symfony\Component\Config\Resource\SelfCheckingResourceChecker
  config_cache_factory                                                                                       Symfony\Component\Config\ResourceCheckerConfigCacheFactory
  dependency_injection.config.container_parameters_resource_checker                                          Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Config\ContainerParametersResourceChecker
```

So, how do I inject the authorization checker into my service?

Comment: Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationCheckerInterface  or '@security.authorization_checker' Hint: bin/console debug:container --show-private | grep Checker

Comment: @Cerad, Yeah. Did that. AuthorizationChecker doesn't show up. Please see Update 1 to my post. Thanks.

Comment: The security component is installed but not the bundle.  "composer require security" assuming you are using flex.

Comment: You were correct about the bundle not being installed. I installed it. Still getting the non-existent sercice "AuthorizationChecker" error.

Comment: See my first comment.  And the alias is for the Interface not the class itself.

Comment: You could also use the syntax presented [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#manually-wiring-arguments) to just define manually the second and third argument and still rely on autowiring for the `AuthorizationChecker`.

Comment: Ah. That's done it. If you put both of those things into an answer, I'll mark it accepted. Thanks!